# Software to mark/label/annotate points/areas in images

Tags: images

Not for AI but for printing or digital display for humans. The software could automatically find the best layout for the label lines and text blobs based on view/print size, label position/density and make their design easily customizable.

macOS,
any price

Comment: Welcome Adler!  Can you please add to your question and tags any operating system and price preferences?  Thanks, and again, welcome!